# Apache - Redirect to a bootstrap

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, centos6

Apache2
    CentOS 6

I am trying to work out how to make an Apache VHost send all of its requests to an index page as a kind of bootstrap. I do not wish to alter the look of URL, however all requests should call the same index.php file..

```
http://url.com/one
http://url.com/
http://url.com/one/two/three
```

The above examples should all land on the index page..

Thanks for any help.. My brain is hurting from this..

EDIT: I seem to get somewhere until i surf to an existing directory.. At this point, the rewrite rules dont seem to work..

Thanks,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project_boot
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_boot

   <Directory "/var/www/html/project_boot">
      AllowOverride None
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index.php [QSA,L]
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `ServerName project_boot` does this actually exist ? i.e. is there a way for a client to land on this vhost and use this hostname ?
Prove (with logs) that anything actually lands on this vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, please direct people to the [**current**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation!

The above "solution" *specifically* causes a [R]edirect - which is not what the OP wants.

Outside your vhost:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Inside your vhost:

```
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

The allowoverride disables any .htaccess files that may exist, and the QSA appends any existing query string to the new URL (if that is what you want).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have added your changes to my VHOST conf, but it appears to not be applying.. I will paste into the OP. Thanks again..

Comment: Ok thank you, i see where i was going wrong.. Almost there now.. I just need to ignore css/js and image files..

Comment: You could pass the rest of the URL as an argument: `RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.php?rest=/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

(Untested)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/.*  /index.ph  [R]
```

Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, didnt work. I tested something like that.. I always ran into the problem of the index.php page being added.. or when a directory that existed was added in the URI, it allowed it through.